# drop duplicate rows from dataframe based on column precedence - python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If I have a database

**Example:**

```
    Name    A    B    C    
0   Jon     0    1    0
1   Jon     1    0    1
2   Alan    1    0    0
3   Shaya   0    1    1
```

If there is a duplicate in my dataset I want the person who has column A as 1 to have precedence.
NB. Column A can only have values 1 or 0

**Output:**

```
    Name    A    B    C    
1   Jon     1    0    1
2   Alan    1    0    0
3   Shaya   0    1    1
```

Comment: What happens when you no duplicates column A is not 1?

Comment: What if A has a value > 1?

Comment: @smci A can only have a value of 1 or 0

Comment: Then please edit the question to say so - it makes a difference to answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC sort value before drop duplicate

```
df.sort_values('A').drop_duplicates('Name',keep='last').sort_index()
Out[126]: 
    Name  A  B  C
1    Jon  1  0  1
2   Alan  1  0  0
3  Shaya  0  1  1
```